# Manage same font size in multiple SVG elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm creating an application using [React Diagrams](http://projectstorm.cloud/react-diagrams/?path=/story/simple-usage--simple-example). In order to create custom nodes I'm using SVGs. A basic custom node react component looks like below and it will be rendered in canvas like area.

```
const S = {
    Container: styled.div<{ height: string; width: string }>`
        width: ${props => props.width};
        height: ${props => props.height};
    `
};


export default (props) => {
    return (
        <S.Container
            width="100px"
            height="100px"
        >
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="20px">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
                <text x="50%" y="50%" textAnchor="middle" ref={text}>
                    Hello World
                </text>
            </svg>
        </S.Container>
    );
};
```

So, I got multiple nodes like those but I'm not able to keep the same font size between those node.

For an example,

```css
#container1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--------------- DIAMOND NODE --------------->
<div id="container1">
    <svg 
    preserveAspectRatio="none" 
    width="100%" 
    height="100%" 
    viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <polygon 
        fill="mediumpurple" 
        stroke="black" 
        strokeWidth="4px" 
        strokeMiterlimit="10" 
        points="0,100 100,0 200,100 100,200" />

        <text 
        x="50%" 
        y="50%" 
        dominant-baseline="middle" 
        text-anchor="middle">
            Hello World
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>

<!--------------- RECT NODE --------------->
<div id="container2">
    <svg 
    width="100%" 
    height="100%">

        <rect 
        x="0" 
        y="0" 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%" 
        fill="white" 
        stroke="black" 
        strokeWidth="4px" />

        <text 
        x="50%" 
        y="50%" 
        dominant-baseline="middle" 
        text-anchor="middle">
            Hello World
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

In `Diamond` node it's important to define `viewBox` because as far as I know it's not possible to define points using percentages. If I change `viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"` and `points="0,500 500,0 1000,500 500,1000"`, text is going to be way smaller. How do I make those `svg` text elements to display the texts at same size

NOTE that I'm keeping size of `svg`s to `100%` because I want to resize the width of the component to match the length of the text, in that case all I have to do is resize the container `div` and `svg` will fill the gaps.

Comment: Why not use a viewBox in both?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we can have nested `SVG`s. That allowed me to have `text` inside the main `SVG` where only width and height are defined. Because I need to associate with points I can create nested `SVG` in which `viewBox` is defined.

```css
#container1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
          <polygon
            fill="mediumpurple"
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="4px"
            strokeMiterlimit="10"
            points="0,100 100,0 200,100 100,200"
          />
        </svg>

        <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
          Hello World
        </text>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div id="container2">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
        </svg>

        <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
          Hello World
        </text>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Give the viewBox for both the node. As view-box helps scaling the SVG's. `link for solution` https://codepen.io/tripti1410/pen/BaapBew?editors=1100

here is the article for more detail https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: I don't want a square. I want a Rectangle.

Comment: Code above was just an example. You need to draw a rect properly in that viewBox.